# Is it incorrect to open a file for writing before it has been closed for reading?

Tags: java, file, inputstream, outputstream, file-descriptor

I am refactoring a small tool which needs to iterate over a list of files and modify them on the fly.

At the moment it performs the modification operation in one method, which means it reads the file to memory, modifies the content within memory, and writes that content back to the same file location.

It is doing so all within a couple of try-with-resource statements. However, this means that the 'open for write' gets done before the read is closed.

I provide here below a small approximation (see method "correctTxt").

To test that, please create a file "FileQuestion.txt" 
with text such as

> The quick brown elephant jumps over the lazy dog

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final File txtFile = new File("FileQuestion.txt");

        correctTxt(txtFile);
    }

    static void correctTxt(File txtFile) throws IOException
    {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(txtFile))))) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line!=null) {
                line = line.replace("elephant", "fox");
                try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(txtFile))) {
                    bos.write(line.getBytes());
                    bos.flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works. It is all done in a single process (single thread).

**The question is,**

Is it fundamentally incorrect to perform the write operation before the close of the read, in the way that is done in the method correctTxt ?

*Note*: It is not intended, after the first read, that any further read be done.

Comment: I would defer to a basic principle of object-oriented development:  Rather than going with code that appears to work, write code that is guaranteed to work.  Closing the InputStream before opening the OutputStream is guaranteed to work.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is not a matter of style or attempting to write perfect object-oriented code, but to find out if, on a purely technical level (low level) there is reason to believe the code might fail.

Comment: I was surprised to discover that the code does not fail on Windows 7, which is notorious for keeping a file locked as long as an InputStream or OutputStream is open.  Aside from Windows, I do not expect it to create a problem.  My point was that unless someone can guarantee it will never be an issue in Windows, I would not take the chance.

Comment: What I would like to know (and I will continue searching, even as I DO refactor the code out of uncertainty) is, if the above code IS valid, is it also somehow faster ? i.e., since the file is already open for the read when the OutputStream is requested, does that mean it uses the same file-descriptor (assuming that means one less operation required on the low-level, one less resource).

Comment: Any difference in speed would be negligible.  Simultaneously open streams will not use the same file descriptor.  If you really want to use the same file descriptor, use `FileChannel.open(txtFile.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)` or `new RandomAccessFile(txtFile, "rw")`.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I'd say it's probably technically not a problem, but... I see is that the scope of the try-with is unnecessarily big and if you would reduce the scope to where it's needed, you wouldn't even be in this situation.

See this version of the correctTxt with minimized try-with scopes

```
static void correctTxt(File txtFile) throws IOException {
    String line;
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(txtFile))))) {
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    if (line!=null) {
        line = line.replace("elephant", "fox");   
        try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(txtFile))) {
            bos.write(line.getBytes());
            bos.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I guess I can do it like this (the actual code is a bit more complicated, and would require a bit more refactoring than this, but in principle I can achieve the same as this).   But I guess I was more asking on a technical low-level basis, if there is reason to believe the code might fail. I am looking for more information on file-access, file-descriptors, how these are managed, low level. A file is locked only per process, yes? Could the open inputstream interfere with the subsequently opened outputstream.. etc